# ignorie when user press Enter or Space

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I need help in my program.
When user press on the keyboard <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> program ignore that.
Like when the button is focused you can just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>, but I want that user can't do like this.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to do so while my program is running it ignores when user press Enter or Space in this program

Answer (score 0):

Just add this function:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
    If msg.WParam.ToInt32() = CInt(Keys.Enter) Or msg.WParam.ToInt32() = CInt(Keys.Space) Then
        Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

valter